# Apache camel wiretap usage

Tags: spring, apache-camel

Can any one give me a hint if it is possible to use

```
.wireTap()
```

like

```
.bean(Test.class, "testMethod(Exchange)");
```

I am trying to create `route` which will process the request by sending right away `processing…` message and at the same time is calling `testMethod` in order to process the order

test case:

```
from("timer:test")
            //.to("log:test")
            .bean(Test.class, "testMethod2()")
            .bean(Test.class, "testMethod(Exchange)");
```

showed that `testMethod` is waiting for `testMethod2` to be ended. I would like to run those two methods asynchronously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the multicast eip in parallel mode

```
from("timer:test")
    .multicast().parallelProcessing().
            .bean(Test.class, "testMethod2()")
            .bean(Test.class, "testMethod(Exchange)")
    .end();
```